# app crashing at FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Tags: java, android

I´m trying to get token by using  `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` in my `MainActivity.java` but **when I use this method to get token, app stars crashing.**

**Here's my onCreate() method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Build.gradle (Project Level)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.gradle (App level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simple.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1')
            {
                force=true
            }
    compile ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2')
            {
                force=true
            }

    compile ('com.android.support:design:25.0.1')
            {
                force=true
            }
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1')
            {
                force=true
            }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0')
            {
                force=true
            }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Logcat**

```
07-25 20:25:20.903 4563-4563/com.simple.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-25 20:25:20.907 4563-4563/com.simple.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.simple.app, PID: 4563
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzx; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx' appears in /data/app/com.simple.app-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes42.dex)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzkg(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.simple.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Are you  using FirebaseInstanceIdService and FirebaseMessagingService class for create token or handle notifications event??

Comment: [I recently faced the same issue but finally got the solution....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54339261/6746324)

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzx;

**FYI**

ASAIK **`getNoBackupFilesDir`** is present in **`android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.`**

- Remove **`support-v4:25.3.1`** from your <kbd>build.gradle</kbd>  dependency section.
- Then **`Clean-Rebuild and Run`**.

It will be better if you use Latest version.

```
android {
    // ...

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    // ...
 }
```

Add

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

And

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    // ...
}
```

> **NOTE**
>
> **`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`** Call to retrieve the current token . If the token has not yet been created, null is
>   returned.

## Monitoring token generation

As the official guideline about [**`Set up a Firebase cloud messaging client app on Android.`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) indicates:

> "The `onTokenRefreshcallback` fires whenever a new token is generated, so calling `getToken` in its context ensures that you are accessing a current, available registration token. Make sure you have added the service to your [manifest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), then call `getToken` in the context of `onTokenRefresh`, and log the value (…)"

### Example

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
```

It worked in my case....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same versions of firebase SDK and support SDK too.

Check dependency tree:

```
./gradlew :{yourappmodulename}:dependencies --configuration compile
```

If you check the tree you will see the different versions:

- Firebase: 9.2.0 and 9.8.0
- Support SDK: 25.0.1 and 25.3.1

You can fix it if you update firebase to 9.8.0 and support SDK to 25.3.1.