# Attempt to invoke virtual method com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am to using `firebase-messaging` library and trying to fetch the token using below method on app launch.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
               String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
               // print token
           }
       });
```

App crashes on the launch itself giving

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId()' on a null object reference
```

AndroidManifest

```
<service
      android:name=".MyFirebaseMessageService">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Also, i have tried to cache the token in SharedPreferences but it seems onNewToken() is never called.

```
@Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
        editor.putString("TOKEN",token);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was problem in merged manifest, following service was missing from the merged manifest.
Added same to `AndroidManifest.xml` it worked like a charm.

```
 <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
 </service>
```

Everything is working fine now.

Comment: It's still crashing for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: for me also still crashing any suggestions?

Comment: @all I will tell you the way i solved it. i created a sample project and used firebase-messaging library and compare the merged manifest of sample project and my original project. You can do the same and findout what is missing from both, add missing entries to your original project and it should work.

Comment: Unable get notification in onMesssageRecieve 
I use the same code above

Comment: facing same issue from 3 days i don't know what is the problem

Comment: @SanjeevKumar Try creating a sample app and compare the merged manifest to see if any entry is missing

Comment: yes you are right i see there was problem of jar file which didn't merged androidmanifest.xml file i fixed it Thanks

Comment: Your welcome @SanjeevKumar !! Dont forget to hit an upvote. xD

Answer (score 0):

I Face the same problem while merging .aar manifest with the main app manifest , As @alphaguy mention that there are missing Components after merging the manifest , And After add the following service as he mention the error is gone :

```
<service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
```

But still firebase Messaging not work because WakefulBroadcastReceiver that receives FirebaseInstanceId and FirebaseMessaging events and delivers them to the application-specific FirebaseInstanceIdService is missing too , This receiver is automatically added to your application's manifest file via manifest merge , in our case it was missing in the merge so we need to add it manually as follow :

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

FirbaseInstanceIdReceiver Documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

- Note : that you may need to add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` at `onCreate` in your `ApplicationClass` .

  ```
  public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need add the below packages,

1. Xamarin.Firebase.Lid
2. Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging
3. Xamarin.Firebase.Common

Optional - Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics (For analytics)