# firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+4 is not working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

ERROR:-

> **Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()' on a null
>   object reference**

Main build.gradle

> dependencies {
>       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
>       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
>   }

App level build.gradle

> dependencies {
>       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
>       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
>       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1' } apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Adroid.manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:largeHeap="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
    until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
    there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
    defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" android:value="true" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692518/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-com-google-firebase-iid-firebaseinstanceid-geti   and try to add that service in your manifest file

Comment: have already tried that and didn't work for me

Comment: Are you sure your problem is coming from dependencies ? Can you show your code where you call getToken method ?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue which i have found the version required of google services for location plugin and FCM plugins are different.

at the app level build.gradle file at the most bottom

```
 dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1' } 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck
    = true
```