# FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize stopped working after adding the package Xamarin.Auth

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I implemented the push notification feature using the package [Plugin.FirebasePushNotification](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.FirebasePushNotification/) and it is working fine. I'm able to receive the notifications. But it stopped working after adding the package [Xamarin.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/). I'm getting the exception '**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzb(boolean) on a null object reference**' at the plugin initialization point.

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);// crashes here
```

I also tried other solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692518/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-com-google-firebase-iid-firebaseinstanceid-geti). But nothing is working in my case. Can someone help me to figure out the issue?

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Try to do a clean and rebuild the project. Also have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/192) may help.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest versions. Firebase alone working fine, but adding Xamarin.Auth caused the error. I tried to clean and rebuild also. It's not resolved my issue.